# Caching and pre-fetching expiring promises in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, memoization, bluebird

Promises are my preferred way of managing my asynchronous code in Javascript.
Memoize (memoizee on npm) is a Javascript library for easily caching & pre-fetching results of functions.

Ideally I want to combine the best of both, and have the ability to "expire" a Promise and pre-fetch a new Promise result (when the cache is touched and near to expiring). Memoize can do this, but it wasn't built with Promises in mind.

(I understand that Promises have a built-in "forever-cache" as is their nature, but *forever* is too long for my application)

My best attempt to do this so far is as follows (node.js example using [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird), [memoize](https://github.com/medikoo/memoize) and [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/)):

```
var memoize = require('memoizee')
  , Promise = require('bluebird')
  , _ = require('underscore')
  ;

// returns a memoized Promise-generating function
function memoizePromiser(funcReturningPromise, options) {
    var opts = _.defaults(options || {}, {async: true});

    return Promise.promisify(memoize(function(){
        var args = _.initial(arguments);
        var cb = _.last(arguments);
        funcReturningPromise.apply(this, args).nodeify(cb);
    }, opts));
};
```

This function will allow me to memoize an async function (with node-like callbacks) returning a promise, whilst also providing all the cache-expiry (+ more) functionality offered by the Memoize library.

However, this approach seems messy and over-engineered to me. I think to myself - surely this is a common enough problem hat someone else has made a more elegant solution?

Is this the best approach for what I'm trying to do? Is there another library like memoize which is designed specifically for promises? Is there a simpler solution that I've missed?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Uh, can you please explain what exactly is wrong with just `memoize(funcReturningPromise, options)`? Maybe I don't understand that there is special behaviour regarding to expiring etc with async functions or so, is there?

Comment: Eureka! Thank you for pointing this out. I was wrapped up in the idea that since I was dealing with async code, I had to make use of the async functionality of memoize (involving the messy node-like callbacks) - but I don't; The promise is returned synchronously.

Comment: I'll make it an answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This function will allow me to memoize an async function (with node-like callbacks) returning a promise. However, this approach seems messy and over-engineered to me.

Yes - you already have a function returning a promise, there is no reason to go back to nodebacks.

> Is there a simpler solution that I've missed?

A function that returns a promise is just a function that returns some value - a value that can be cached by the `memoize` function. Simply do

```
memoize(funcReturningPromise, options)
```

Comment: What happens if funcReturningPromise fails? Are you caching the failure?

Comment: @PhilC: Yes, in that case the rejected promise would be cached. I would think however that this expected, the aim of memoisation is to prevent multiple requests. If you don't want that, you still can catch rejections, or purge the memoisation cache.

Comment: Got it. I was looking at it to store good values only so as you say I need to catch rejections and make sure they do not go into the cache- thanks

Comment: @PhilC: Notice that to properly work the promise should go into the cache *before* you can know that it will be rejected. So without a solution that prevents promises from ever rejecting (e.g. retry), you'd want to *remove* the promise from the cache it already is in on rejection.

Answer (score 0):

You understand promises correctly - a promise is a proxy for a value - once it's set it will never change.

The *only* way around this is to not return the same promise each time - you'd have to return a different promise each time (like your example does). The simplest solution would be to use `memoize` with promise returning functions (and it'd cache the *promise* for the value).

If we have a `function foo(){` that returns a promise. It's perfectly fine to just `memoize` that function itself and then use all the tools the library provides.

Note: `promisify` is expensive and produces a very fast function - you really don't want to call it at runtime. You could simply return `new Promise` in your code.