# Patterns for returning same promise after calling method multiple times

Tags: javascript, promise

Given i have a method that performs async operation and returns promise that gets resolve when that operation is done - how do i make sure that when called multiple times before that operation is done i get as a result same promise.
**Edit** when i call it after operation is done - i want to get new promise for current operation..

One option is to remember call ( memoize ) and eg track promise by a variable in outer scope

```
var p;
function test() {
   if (p) return p;
   p = new Promise(res) {
       res();
       p = null;
   }
   return p;
}
```

Any other nicer solutions?

Comment: I guess your actual promise is not resolved synchronously like the one in your non-working example?

Comment: Don't forget to handle rejections appropriately (in whatever way that might be)

Comment: Related question: [Caching and pre-fetching expiring promises in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26485662/caching-and-pre-fetching-expiring-promises-in-javascript).

Answer (score 1):

The approach You're using here is called [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) and it's hard to come up with anything nicer.

What You might want to do is to split the tedious bits (save in outer scope, reuse, delete) from the function itself. Or even use a [library](https://github.com/elado/reuse-promise):

```
import reusePromise from 'reuse-promise';

function test() {
   return new Promise(function (res) {
       res();
   });
}

const reusableTest = reusePromise(test);
```

### Full example

```js
"use strict";

const reusePromise = require('reuse-promise').default;

let i = 0;
function test() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(i++), 100);
  });
}

const reusableTest = reusePromise(test);

reusableTest().then(console.log).catch(console.err);
reusableTest().then(console.log).catch(console.err);
reusableTest().then(console.log).catch(console.err);

setTimeout(() => {
  reusableTest().then(console.log).catch(console.err);
  reusableTest().then(console.log).catch(console.err);
  reusableTest().then(console.log).catch(console.err);
}, 200);

// output: 0 0 0 1 1 1
```

Comment: Yes, memoization fits here nicely - but forgot about one requirement - reset state when operation is done, so next call to the fn would give me new promise.. memoize again . ..it can be of course done easily

Comment: It is totally covered by the library. I've added an example to my answer that illustrates this case.